# Missing required library classes_managed

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0

Im using play 2.0 and trying to modularize the project into a subproject.
In $project_home, created folder structure ${project_home}/data/app/models/MyModel.java

The Build.scala looks

```
val dataDependencies = Seq(
)

val dataProject = PlayProject(appName + "-data", appVersion, dataDependencies, path = file("data"), mainLang = JAVA)

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
  // Add your own project settings here      
).dependsOn(dataProject).aggregate(dataProject)
```

I run a play eclpsify command.

In eclipse, I've imported two projects, the main project and the data project.

The data project shows the following error

Project '-data' is missing required library: '/path/to/myprojects/data/target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed'

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the similar problem when building a project with play 2.0.2
I created manually the `target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed` folder and I run `clean all` projects in eclipse

I hope it helps

Comment: hi to all,
someone knows how do this with new version of  "play framework" where the classes_managed folder doesn't exist? i tryed to add all folders i found but nothing.

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me (on Windows).

1. Edit **.classpath**, there should be an entry similar to this:
   `<classpathentry path="D:\your_play_project_folder\target\scala-2.10\classes_managed" kind="lib"></classpathentry>`
2. Remove the path portion before "target" to get this:
   `<classpathentry path="target\scala-2.10\classes_managed" kind="lib"></classpathentry>`
3. Refresh Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 3 possibilities:

1. create data/target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed manually.
2. Remove the path from class-path (if not necessary)
3. Switch to 2.1-snapshot

Answer (score 2):

For me helped:

1. manually removed target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed from the .classpath file
2. added target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed via eclipse: project/properties/Java Build Path --> tab Libraries --> Add Class Folder...

Answer (score 1):

Try "play clean" and then "play eclipse", to re-generate the eclipse project files from a command prompt in the project's base folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
1) sbt> clean/compile in parent, followed by child project
2) add target/src-managed/main as source folder in eclipse, both projects
3) in child
java build path > projects > (add parent)
project references > (add parent)
```

What does dataProject do, btw? My base project provides a DAO layer and other nuts & bolts that have nothing to do with Play; therefore, I just define it as a root sbt project, and pull it in to child project via `dependsOn(root)`

Anyway, hope this gets the issue sorted...